Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: dev/failsafe/Policy
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.http/org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ClientConfig.<clinit>(ClientConfig.java:33)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:83)
    at org.seleniumhq.selenium.chrome_driver/org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:51)
    at Selenium/demos.Login.main(Login.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: dev.failsafe.Policy
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 4 more

Getting this error for this code:
package demos;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Login {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/aarsh/Downloads/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://rahulshettyacademy.com/loginpagePractise/");
    }
}


Are you using a build tool? Can you please include your dependencies? How are you running the application?

Yes i am using maven
I have added selenium-java , testng and cucumber dependencies

@aarshasunil, this question have some differences with your example. Check if it help you. And add maven tag to your question.
